# Hierarchical Bayes for R or Python

Tags: python, r, statistics

Hierarchical Bayes models are commonly used in Marketing, Political Science, and Econometrics. Yet, the only package I know of is `bayesm`, which is really a companion to a book (*Bayesian Statistics and Marketing*, by Rossi, et al.) Am I missing something? Is there a software package for R or Python doing the job out there, and/or a worked-out example in the associated language?

Comment: Generally speaking, those are three subject Computer Science folk try to avoid.  Sorry.

Comment: I'm so glad that the computer scientists try to avoid marketing, poly sci, and econometrics. If they decided to get into those fields I anticipate that my salary would be cut in half by competition! But that would be an economic issue, I presume. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are four books on hierarchical modeling and bayesian analysis written with R code throughout the books.

Hierarchical Modeling and Analysis for Spatial Data (Monographs on Statistics and Applied Probability) (Hardcover)
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/158488410X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/158488410X)

Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models (Paperback)
[http://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Regression-Multilevel-Hierarchical-Models/dp/052168689X/ref=pd_sim_b_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052168689X)

Bayesian Computation with R (Use R) (Paperback)
[http://www.amazon.com/Bayesian-Computation-R-Use/dp/0387922970/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_c](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387922970)

Hierarchical Modelling for the Environmental Sciences: Statistical Methods and Applications (Oxford Biology) (Paperback) (I'm assuming this one has R code as both authors use R extensively)

I know some python books dabble in multivariate analysis (Collective Intelligence, for example) but I haven't seen any that really delve into bayesian or hierarchical modeling.

Answer (score 13):

There's OpenBUGS and R helper packages.  Check out Gelman's site for his book, which has most of the relevant links:

- http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/software/
- [Example of computation in R and Bugs](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/bugsR/software.pdf)

On the Python side, I only know of PyMC:

- http://code.google.com/p/pymc/
- [An example statistical model](http://pymc.googlecode.com/svn/doc/tutorial.html)

EDIT:  Added a link to the appropriate appendix from Gelman's book, available online, for an example using R and BUGS.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few hierarchical models in [MCMCpack](http://mcmcpack.wustl.edu) for R, which to my knowledge is the fastest sampler for many common model types. (I wrote the [hierarchical item response][2] model in it.)

[RJAGS][3] does what its name sounds like. Code up a jags-flavored .bug model, provide data in R, and call Jags from R.

Answer (score 3):

in python, try PyMC.  There is an example of multilevel modeling with it here:  http://groups.google.com/group/pymc/browse_thread/thread/c6ce37a80edf7f85/1bfd9138c8db891d

Comment: I'd add that PyMC is close enough to WinBUGS (in my experience) that if you have a text teaching you with WinBUGS (or presumably JAGS), you could easily write your own PyMC code.

Answer (score 2):

I apply hierarchical Bayes models in R in combination with JAGS (Linux) or sometimes WinBUGS (Windows, or Wine).  Check out the book of Andrew Gelman, as referred to above.

Answer (score 0):

The lme4 package, which estimates hierarchical models using frequentist methods, has a function called mcmcsamp that allows you to sample from the posterior distribution of the model using MCMC. This currently  works only for linear models, quite unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes almost ten years late, but it will hopefully help someone in the future.

The `brms` package in R is a very good option for Bayesian hierarchical/multilevel models, using a syntax very similar to the `lme4` package.

The `brms` package uses the probabilistic programming language Stan in the back to do the inferences. Stan uses more advanced sampling methods than JAGS and BUGS, such as Hamiltonian Monte Carlo, which provides more efficient and reliable samples from the posterior distribution.

If you wish to model more complicated phenomena, then you can use the `rstan`package to compile Stan models from R. There is also the Python alternative `PyStan`. However, in order to do this, you must learn how to use Stan.